# How to check if a file has an extension (any extension) with regular expression in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to Bash Scripting using Ubuntu18.04 and trying to find if a file has an extension (any extension) but the regular expression I am trying to implement is not working. I have been using the same regular expression in Perl script and it is working fine. But it does not work in Bash Script.
Below is my Bash Code:

```
dir="ImageFolder"
fileName=""
for f in "$dir"/*;
do
    fileName="$(basename "$f")"

if [[ $fileName =~ /(.*)?\.(.*)/ ]]
then
    echo $fileName
    echo "Yes it has extension"
fi
done
```

It does not execute those echo commands even though the files inside "ImageFolder" has their extensions. In other words, the "if" statement is not executing. It only gets executed when I invert the condition by placing a `'!'` symbol before `'$fileName'`.
When I invert the condition: `if [[ ! $fileName =~ /(.*)?\.(.*)/ ]]` then it executes but gives undesired outputs (Please See Image):
[It displays files with extension and says yes it has extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FntMC.png)

But when I actually remove file extensions by going physically inside the folder then again it executes and says file extension exists (Please see image)
[Says 'Yes It has extensions even though I've removed them'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRUzU.png)

I really need this regular expression to work. Some help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: A very simple solution (without lots of false positives, though) would be `[[ $filename = *.* ]]`, using pattern matching instead of regular expressions.

Comment: (Sorry, I meant to say *with* false positives, such as `.bashrc` and `foo.`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work once you remove the '/' surrounding the regex pattern.

```
[[ $fileName =~ (.*)?\.(.*) ]]
```

ref. https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html#REGEXMATCHREF for more examples.

Comment: Wow! It did work. I tried to upvote your answer but my reputation is below 15 therefore, it is not getting reflected publicly. Anyways, Thanks for the answer and the reference. I heartily appreciate that.

Comment: @fpmurphy No it won't, not inside double square brackets.

Comment: This needs some adjustments to handle some corner cases. You probably don't want to consider a file like `.bashrc` to have an extension, and it's not clear how to handle a file name that ends with a `.`. Does `foo.` have an extension? `foo.bar.`?

Comment: Hi @chepner, The aforementioned Regular expression will always point to the word after the last dot. I ran your idea and you are right. If you have any other regular expression then you can also mention that as well. It would be great to know. Thanks!!

Comment: One other corner-corner case: do you want to match any hidden files with an extension? (For example, a Vim swap file like `.tmp.txt.swp`)